# Do I need to mention having survived a life-threatening illness when applying for a new academic position?

Tags: etiquette, application, health

Do I have to (or is it wise or unwise) to mention having survived a life-threatening illness (such as cancer, a (early) heart attack, etc when applying for a new (non-leading) academic position?

Assume that my health condition is now good enough (and the past health troubles are not obvious from my outward appearance) such that from a medical point of view nothing speaks against my further persuing my academic career and interests.

Nevertheless, due the specific medicaments I have to take for the rest of my life and some remnants of the past health issues, there might be times my productivity might slightly be lessened. Also, even though the probability is not very high, it can in principle not be 100% excluded that the illness will come back at some point.

Of course I would not mention this in a written application, but should I talk about my health condition in the context of an interview or before things are getting serious and it comes to signing the contract?

BTW I currently live in Germany

Answer (score 25):

**If you think it helps explain a work or productivity gap in your career, I would mention it and I would do so in writing rather than let your prospective employers speculate.** Because overcoming a major medical challenge can help you align your priorities and strengthen you in other ways, doing so can definitely be done in a way that leads one to conclude that it is a strength, not a weakness, of your candidacy.

**If your previous condition is not relevant in these ways, I don't think you have any obligation to bring it up.** Sure, your illness *might* return but *nobody* is 100% immune from serious illness impacting their ability to work or be productive. For that matter, severe chronic illnesses that unambiguously affect productivity (e.g., cramps, migraines, etc.) are simply not the kind of thing that people bring up while interviewing and candidates have no responsibility to do so.

Reminding prospective employers of this can open to the door to (illegal) discrimination based on your medical history and I don't think you are helping either yourself or your prospective employers by bringing it up. When you take an offer, it might be good to let your future department know about your history as background but you might even let this just be raised socially.

Comment: Good answer.  One other point is that you may want to carefully study your prospective employer's insurance, medical leave, and disability policies.  For an institution like a university, sometimes these are publicly posted; otherwise you could contact someone in the human resources office and ask any questions you have.  As far as I know, they would not have any reason to tell the hiring committee you were asking, so it shouldn't affect the interview process in any way.

Comment: As @NateEldredge notes, it's imperative to look at the insurance/benefits situation. In particular, there still remains the possibility that insurance refuses to cover "pre-existing conditions" of certain sorts. This should _not_ be the case for academic situations, but one should look carefully.

Comment: @NateEldredge However, this is relevant only to some countries (U.S. for sure, I dunno about others), and it is irrelevant for most European countries (where the health insurance is government-based and not company-based).

Comment: @yo' Or in the case of some countries where they have free health care (which you could argue is government based, but technically it's not really insurance in the normal sense)

Answer (score 7):

If you live in the United States, you are not obligated to provide any information pertinent to disability, including life-threatening illness.
What with competition for jobs being so fierce, you may find yourself
overtly or covertly discriminated against in favour of someone who is
healthier.  That's why the Americans with Disabilities Act was passed
into law.  Any questions regarding your health from an employer are
also illegal, so you are not obligated to answer.

Comment: The asker did not specify that they live in the US - your country-specific information may not be of any use to them. It's still good advice, but it's too specific without first confirming which country's laws apply to the asker.

Comment: from what I understand, protections in Canada, France and the UK are even stronger than the US.

Comment: Yes, but you're still making assumptions about where the asker lives, they might live somewhere where such discrimination is not only legal but socially acceptable. I know it's unlikely, but it's still possible, you should always ask rather than make assumptions.

Comment: @Pharap nah I am not in the US, but the information is a good one to have anyway as (who knows?) maybe at some point I will be there and others already are.

Comment: @Pharap, even if I am making assumptions, I believe the OP is still not morally obligated to disclose.  No deceit is present because I do not consider it dishonest to lie to a tyrant, which companies outside US jurisdiction who would discriminate about it amount to.

Comment: @Dilaton Since employment and discrimination law does vary so much from country to country, it would be helpful if you would edit the question to say where you are.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This is kind of my point. Instead of making assumptions, it's much easier to simply ask the OP which laws apply to them.

Comment: @Dilaton I admitted in my very first comment the advice was good advice, I just think it's bad practice to assume the OP of any question on the stack exchange is from a certain country - especially when laws come into play.