# Affect of not finishing degree within 3 years due to a disease

Tags: graduate-admissions, academic-life

I am currently pursuing a degree in bsc. Hons is of 3 years in an esteemed university in india. I am at the final year now. Through the two year my grade was of around 7 cgpa. But at the last semester I am affected with a disease and can't appear in the exam for final semester. Although I am pretty sure I can complete the degree within 4th year, but my dream is to go to foreign so I am scared that it may hamper my dream to get admission in grad school in foreign universities, despite of having good work experiences as I have done 3 internships and one conference. So it will be great if any one can tell me how much not finishing my degree within 4 years will affect my chance of getting a good grad school.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122576/will-my-cancer-ruin-my-chances-of-going-to-graduate-school-in-math

Comment: I am afraid that although I am not taking 8 years of my life but my disease isn't as serious as cancer although serious enough so I have to get admit to hospital. So I am concern about that after reading it also

Comment: My intention was not to compare your disease to cancer, my intention was to point you towards answers that have been previously given. I think those previous answers will help answer your question, at least in part.